# python sharing variables between active threads

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, global-variables

I have a program which runs a camera for a set number of exposures and a set length of exposures through a serial port.  The program talks to a server which gives error values, if the error values are within an acceptable range, then the exposure starts and a countdown clock runs until the exposure ends. The following variables are used to make this happen.

T="Length of exposure in seconds"
N="Number of exposures"

then a while loop runs the program using the following

```
    def countdown(n):
       for i in range(int(n)):
        c = int(n) - int(i)
        print c ,'seconds left','\r',
        time.sleep(1)  

While x < T loop: 
        countdown(n)
```

I would like to run a thread which is constantly probing the error number from the server, and if the error number grows to large, it changes to the value of i to equal n.

```
def errortest():
                    test=struct.pack("B",10)
                    s.send(test)
                    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    if ord(data) < (75) and ord(data) > 0:
                        print ord(data)
                        time.sleep(5)
                    else:
                        print ("error! Stopping exposure")
                        i=n
```

My problem is that the variables aren't being shared between the functions.  I had some success with setting "i" and "n" as global variables, but this has caused other problems as well, depending on the order in which I invoke or write the different functions.  I've also tried return i=n, but n is not shared.  It is especially a problem as both threads are running concurrently and not sharing variables.  This is why I cannot get queue to work because it pauses the for loop at each instance of q.get().

Is there a better way than using global variables to share variable values between functions running as concurrent threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try sharing your variables within a [class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). You'll find many [tutorials](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/) if you google for them. If you want to distribute your tasks into different programs, [xmlrpc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) is a simple possibility.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding classes.  Classes are essentially local environments that are analogous to the global environment?  Ie I set a global variable and all functions in the environment can use that variable.   I set a class variable and all functions within that class can see that variable?

Comment: Basically yes and it is a very useful concept. Each variable in Python is the instance of a class. E.g. a string variable has other functions and local variables as a list or a number.